# putty- connection error network timeout just for first try

Tags: ssh, putty, connection, timeout

I use Putty application for SSH.

When I try to remote connection to my server, "ONLY FIRST CONNECTION TRY" failed to connect with "connection timeout" message.

And one more try, connection is done.

If I capture packet, there is no ssh packet when my first try.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the server? How did you try to capture packet?

Comment: The Server is my company's intranet, and I used Wireshark to capture packets.

Comment: it fails during TCP connection establishing, so there is no SSH packet. Can you `ping` the server "for the first try"? Can you `traceroute` to the server "for the first try"? What is the network configuration between you and the server? Too much unanswered questions.

Comment: I tried ping test. Destination server IP is 192.168.8.54 and result is first line: "192.168.8.1 Destination host unreachable", second line: "192.168.8.54 response <= 32ms........... " As a result, It seems to not able to find gateway. Am I right? How can I fix it?

Comment: I seem to have exactly the same issue with Putty (and other software) on Windows 10. Any updates ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VirtualBox installed by any chance?  Or another VM manager?  I was having the same problem and my IP configuration for VirtualBox had a duplicate IP.  I think there was a conflict somehow.  I don't know whether this is your problem.. However, in order to fix it (in Windows) Disable the network interface and bring it back up.  (For windows this disabled the Virtual Network Interface as well.)  Then, bring it back up.  This left the Virtual Interface disabled and it pinged fine the first time.  I could also connect with PuTTY the first time as well.  Then just re-assign your Virtual Machine Manager to a new address preferably to a static IP address.

Comment: Great hint! The VirtualBox network adapters were causing me a very similar issue with Putty not working on the first try, even with no double assigned IP and when VirtualBox wasn't running at all.