# Windows 10 sends ARP request only on 2nd attempt to reach the IP

Tags: windows-10, networking, troubleshooting, arp

When I try to open a TCP connection from my Windows 10 laptop to an IP on my LAN that is not present in the ARP cache (eg. when the laptop comes back from sleep), the connection fails on the first attempt. The 2nd attempt works fine.

I verified that this always happens when the IP is not in the ARP cache (checked with `arp -a`) and can be reproduced by deleting the ARP entry with `arp -d x.x.x.x`.

In Wireshark I see that Windows does not send an ARP request on the first connection attempt.

Any ideas what might be mis-configured and how I can fix this ?

Comment: One conjecture might be that it takes too long to get the answer for the ARP request, so that the first connect times out, but the ARP answer does arrive in time for the second attempt. If this is what's happening, then the question is where is the slow-down (maybe router/switch) and what is the target device. We need more information about your network architecture and devices. Perhaps increasing the timeout period might help.

Comment: See [TCP/IP Configuration Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739819(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with attention to `TcpInitialRTT` and `TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions`.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, but using Wireshark I verified that the ARP requests aren't even _sent_ on the first connection attempt.

Comment: Questions: How are you connecting: OS, program, target? What is the local network architecture, router etc?

Comment: @harrymc: I have the latest Windows 10 installed, to connect out, I'm using Putty to connect to a Linux machine on the same LAN. The Windows 10 laptop is connected by wifi to a Fritzbox router and the Linux machine is connected with a LAN cable directly to the router.

Comment: Does it work better if the Windows machine is connected via cable?

Comment: No change with a cable.

Comment: Have you tried another software than Putty? (Asking because of [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1016980/putty-connection-error-network-timeout-just-for-first-try)) What is the error on the first attempt (timeout?). Are you using IPv4 or IPv6 or both? If both, try to disable IPv6.

Comment: I have both IPv4 and IPv6. I disabled IPv6 and tried with telnet. Same thing...

Comment: This is too weird. What make are your computer and network adapter (and which driver)? Is Windows the latest version 2004?

Comment: Its a Fujitsu laptop Lifebook A557. Windows 10 version is 20H2, but I had the issue with 2004 also.

Comment: The Fujitsu website is very bad at finding BIOS and drivers updates, maybe you could check it better from your computer. My last idea: [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Fujitsu ships a tool ("DeskUpdate") that automatically searches for BIOS and other updates and I'm on the latest version. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: One more: https://serverfault.com/a/367668/18736

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119486/discussion-between-gene-vincent-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause:
`VirtualBox` had installed 3 network adapters and even while VirtualBox wasn't running at all, they seem to interfere with the networking.

After disabling or deleting them, connections started to work on the first try.

I delete all 3 adapters from within VirtualBox (Windows didn't let me delete them directly).

Interestingly, VirtualBox seems to run fine, including network connections, without the adapters.